# What is the process of finding deep links from an Android application?

Tags: android, java, uri

I'm very curious on how to go about this the only solution i can think of is to decompile, modify the code to print when a deep link is clicked, and recompile, if you have any other suggestions i would be very happy to hear!

Comment: Welcome to the site! As far as I can tell, [deep links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) are URLs that an app can handle. For example a map app might be able to handle `openstreetmap.org/#map=<lat>/<lon>/<zoom>` and be able to open that location. Aren't those URL handlers simply contained in the AndroidManifest file? See the `<data ...` tag in the first code block on the page that I linked. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Luc Yeah but as far as i can tell there is no way to get the android manifest by decompiling an apk file, And i mean more like fb:// or the more modern intent://p#Intent;scheme=fb;package=com.facebook:end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A deep link is similar to opening a URL with an application in other operating systems. You can run `firefox https://example.com` to open that URL in your browser, and applications can tell the operating system that they can handle certain protocols (such as `myapp://some/place`).

In Android, the way to tell the operating system what your app can handle, is by using the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This is explained in the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

To extract that file from an APK (Android Package), you used to be able to just `unzip your.apk`. These days, that will still work, but the XML is transformed into a binary format, so you need special tools to extract it. Most commonly, one would use [apktool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4191807/1201863) or [aapt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231483/1201863).

Taking [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) as example (I know it can open `f-droid.org` links):

```
$ wget https://f-droid.org/f-droid.apk
$ apktool d f-droid.apk
$ cd f-droid
$ cat AndroidManifest.xml
[...]
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="f-droid.org"/>
            <data android:host="www.f-droid.org"/>
            <data android:host="staging.f-droid.org"/>
            <data android:pathPrefix="/app/"/>
            <data android:pathPrefix="/packages/"/>
            <data android:pathPrefix="/repository/browse"/>
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*/packages/.*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*/packages/.*/"/>
        </intent-filter>
[...]
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="play.google.com"/>
            <data android:path="/store/apps/details"/>
        </intent-filter>
[...]
```

We see that f-droid will open `https://f-droid.org`, `https://www.f-droid.org`, `https://staging.fdroid.org`, but a little further down we also find that it can also handle Google Play Store URLs. There are some more, but I'll leave those as an exercise to the reader :-). Look for the `<data ...` tags.

Comment: perfect explanation thank you, exactly what i was looking for.